Adding Multiple Authentication Schemes to a .NET Application
Currently we are having Auth0 as the authentication mechanism for accountants. We would like to add .Net Identity for admin users.
Below is my code
// Accountants
configurationbuilder.Services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication("AccountantScheme", options =>{    options.Domain = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]; 
options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];    options.Scope = "openid profile email";
options.OpenIdConnectEvents = new OpenIdConnectEvents    {        OnAccessDenied = context =>        {            context.Response.Redirect("/");            context.HandleResponse();            return Task.FromResult(0);        }    }; 
options.CookieAuthenticationScheme = "AccountantCookies"; }).WithAccessToken(options =>{    options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:ManagementAudience"];    options.UseRefreshTokens = true;});

builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>("AccountantCookies", options =>{    options.LoginPath = "/AccountantPortal/Authentication/LogIn/Login";    options.LogoutPath = "/AccountantPortal/Authentication/LogOut/Logout";});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]));

//Admins
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure custom Identity cookie settings for Admins
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>{    options.Cookie.Name = "AdminIdentityCookies";    options.LoginPath = "/AdminPortal/Account/Login";    options.LogoutPath = "/AdminPortal/Account/Logout";    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AdminPortal/Account/AccessDenied";});

When I login from Auth0, it's using the default Identity scheme
My application is using .net 8

First, this is covered in the docs, in Multiple Authentication Providers. Second, this snippet is unreadable. It's impossible to see whether the correct calls were made or not

You could set the authorization policy with to set the required role and authentication scheme.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AccountantPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("AccountantScheme");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });

    options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Identity.Application");
        policy.RequireRole("Admin");
    });
});

Then you could use it as below:
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminPolicy")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller


[Authorize(Policy = "AccountantPolicy")]
public class EmployeeController : Controller

